# Why the parameter --auto-reload is not working if the addons path content are links to modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, pyinotify

**Description**

Normally if you change your python code means, you need to restart the server in order to apply the new changes.

If the `--auto-reload` parameter is enabled means, you don't need to restart the server. It enables auto-reloading of python files and xml files without having to restart the server. It requires [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki). It is a Python module for monitoring filesystems changes.

**Previous Problem**

I got the error:

```
ERROR ? pyinotify: add_watch: cannot watch /home/user/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0 WD=-1, Errno=No space left on device (ENOSPC)
```

But I followed the advice of [this link](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) and now I don't get that error anymore:

```
sysctl -n -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384
```

After this I got this in the server log:

```
openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder /opt/odoo_8/src/linked-addons
openerp.service.server: AutoReload watcher running
```

That means that's working properly. And in fact I tested it with a physical addon path and it worked.

**Current Problem**

I have all my modules en several folders but I only use one addons path: `/opt/odoo_8/src/linked-addons`. This folder contains all the links of the modules that I'm using. All modules are working well when I run Odoo.

But the problem is that pyinotify is not able to check the files beyond the links and it doesn't reload the files well. What I should do to fix this? Is there a way that pyinotify can recognise the content of the links?

PD: I don't want to change my way of managing the modules folders in Odoo.

Comment: Might be worth looking at watchdog https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

Comment: Thanks! But I prefer to use pyinotify because I can use it with the odoo launcher

Comment: There is a module(http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/zaber-custom/files/head:/module_reload/) that adds a button `Reload` to openerp next upgrade button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found is to isolate the custom modules in a different folder. I have added the new folder to the addons path in the configuration file and now everything works fine

```
addons_path = /opt/odoo_8/src/linked-addons,/opt/odoo_8/src/custom
```

PD: I saved the module folders directly in the `custom` folder instead of saving the links to the folders.